# Family of diffeomorphisms on a Manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-manifolds

I am reading Huybrechts book Complex Geometry.

On page 259, below Def.6.1.3: the author talks about families of diffeomorphism and then he gives a power series expansion and uses it to define a vector field.

[image]

If necessary, we may assume the manifold is compact.

Q1: How did we get the power series expansion?

Q2:  Is $\frac{dF_t}{dt}|_{t=0} = \sum_i F_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i }$ just a notation? or is it a formula?

Could someone help understand this part, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose M is $R^n$, $F_t(x)$ is a smooth function on $(-1,1)\times M$, $F: (t,x)\mapsto F_t(x)$ so it can be expanded with respect to $t$ in a neighbor of 0, $F_t(x)=x+t\cdot\frac{dF}{dt}(x)|_{t=0}+o(t)$. (Note $F_0=id$, so $F_0(x)=x$). And$\frac{dF}{dt}(x)|_{t=0}=(\frac{dF^1}{dt}, \frac{dF^2}{dt}, \dots, \frac{dF^n}{dt})=\sum{\frac{dF^i}{dt}\frac{\partial}{\partial{x^i}}}$.
For a general manifold just do that in a coordinate chart.

Comment: @Xiao  Thank you.  I guess you meant $\frac{dF_t}{dt}(x)|_{t=0}$ on the LHS of the last equation, right?  But if you look at series given in my question above, the author  writes $F_i$ instead of $\frac{dF}{dt}$, is it a typo or am I missing something?

Comment: The author's $F_i$ is defined to be my $\frac{dF^i}{dt}$, where my $F^i$ is the i-th component of F. You can always try to understand with examples. For example, let $M=R^2$ and $F_t(x)=x+(t,0)$, try to compute all the terms.

Comment: Thanks again.  Your notation is clear and makes much more sense than the original notation.